# Get Sitecore From submission attempts

Tags: experience-analytics, sitecore-forms, mvc-forms

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8, I created a simple Sitecore form with submit button, I want to disable the submit button after certain count of submission, Is it possible to achieve this in an OOB solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box solution in Sitecore forms for your scenario.

I just checked the conditional logic feature in Sitecore Forms, the IF part of the condition cannot be applied on a submit button field (Sitecore Forms doesn't allow you to do so on a submit button), though there is an option in the THEN part of the condition to disable the submit button.